# Listview Item with both foreground and background together

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

[image]

I am trying to set the foreground color of a listview item on multi select of items. But my problem is it is collapsing with the background attribute of listview item. How do I set the foreground to ?attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator without collision with background drawable selector. I have the background drawable set to selector_card_bg which displays card like item. Now, on selecting these items , I want the selected items to be highlighted as in the screenshot.

listview_item:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/selector_card_bg"
android:foreground="?attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
android:padding="5dp" >
```

selector_card_bg:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
  android:state_pressed="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/card_background_pressed" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/card_background" />
</selector>
```

card_background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
  <shape android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="#CABBBB"/>
     <corners android:radius="2dp" />
  </shape>
</item>

<item
  android:left="0dp"
  android:right="0dp"
  android:top="0dp"
  android:bottom="2dp">
  <shape android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="#4f334e"/>
     <corners android:radius="2dp" />
  </shape>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

**UPDATE:** 
Able to achieve by adding the code in getView of adapter. But getView is called so many times because of this. Any suggestions to improve this?

```
 if(mSelectedItemsIds!=null && mSelectedItemsIds.get(position, false))
    {
        Log.d("tag","if triggered"+mSelectedItemsIds+"position is="+position);
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color
                .parseColor("#CCCCCC"));
    }
    else 
    {
        Log.d("tag","else triggered"+mSelectedItemsIds+"position is="+position); // how to restrict this else loop from getting called always
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_card_bg);

    }
```

Comment: I think a few screenshots of what you are trying to achieve would help.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry  Any suggestions to improve my solution? mSelectedItemsIds is a SparseBooleanArray.